# C : Mergesort - what is the mistake? Wrong output (repetition)

Tags: c, mergesort

I have written this "mergesort" in C. I think somewhere there is mistake in copying back the elements to original array.
can someone help me?

Huge lots of thanks in advance.

```
enter code here

 /*************************** Merge sort ********************************/
  #include <stdio.h>

  void merge(int arr[], int start1, int end1, int start2, int end2)
  {
   int temp[100], beg1, beg2, i;

   beg1=start1;
   beg2=start2;
   i=0;

   while((beg1<=end1)&&(beg2<=end2))
   {
     if(arr[beg1]<arr[beg2])
      {
        temp[i++]=arr[beg1++];
      }
     else
      {
        temp[i++]=arr[beg2++];
      }
   }
   if(beg1<end1) {
       while(beg1<=end1) temp[i++]=arr[beg1++];
   }

  if(beg2<end2) {  
       while(beg2<=end2) temp[i++]=arr[beg2++];
  }

  i=0;
  for(beg1=start1; beg1<=end1; beg1++)
  {
      arr[beg1]=temp[i++];
  }
 for(beg1=start2; beg1<=end2; beg1++)
  {
      arr[beg1]=temp[i++];
  }
}

 void mergesort(int arr[], int beg, int end)
 {
   int mid;

   if(beg<end) {
      mid=(beg + end)/2;
      mergesort(arr, beg, mid);
      mergesort(arr, mid+1, end);
      merge(arr, beg, mid, mid+1, end);
   }
 }

 int main()
 {
   int i;
   int arr[]={34, 3, 10, 78, 4, 0, 14};
   mergesort(arr, 0, 6);

   printf("Here are the sorted elements:\n");

   for(i=0; i<6; i++){
      printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
 }

Output:
  [root@dhcppc0 sorting]# gcc mergesort.c
  [root@dhcppc0 sorting]# ./a.out

     Here are the sorted elements:
          0       0       3       0       10      10
```

Comment: A good way to debug this sort of problem is to print out the elements of the array during the intermediate steps (like you do at the end). That often makes it clear where things are going wrong.

Comment: I accept, but if you have any readymade algo for this, can you please help? My interview time is too less, and loads of other preparations. Also, this is a recursive program, printing the elements can be very cumbersome. GDB can help, but again the time factor.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Are you saying this is for a current interview?

Comment: Your interview time?  Isn't an interview something you're supposed to do on your own?

Comment: Printing the elements in a recursive function can be cumbersome, but since you can reproduce the problem with only a 7-element array, it's not going to be too bad. One handy technique when using print to debug a recursive function is to have a global variable determining level of indentation. Have your print_elements function start by printing that many spaces, and increment the variable when you enter mergesort() and decrement it when you leave.

Comment: @John: Yes, interview i am supposed to do on my own, but not the interview preparation.

Comment: @dfan: Looks some good idea, what do you mean by "global variable determining level of indentation"? Can you please help me with some more clarification? And may be an example if possible?

Answer (score 1):

`end1` and `end2` are valid indices, so I don't think yo should have those `if` statements here

```
if(beg1<end1) {
   while(beg1<=end1) temp[i++]=arr[beg1++];
}

if(beg2<end2) {  
   while(beg2<=end2) temp[i++]=arr[beg2++];
}
```

what if `beg1` == `end1`?

if `beg1<end1`, you have at least 2 array elements left in the range [beg1, end1]. If there is only one, you should copy it too. You should leave the loops unguarded by the if statements. Change the code presented above to:

```
//if(beg1<end1) {
   while(beg1<=end1) temp[i++]=arr[beg1++];
//}

//if(beg2<end2) {  
   while(beg2<=end2) temp[i++]=arr[beg2++];
//}
```

On a side note, your sort is not stable. To fix it, change this condition

```
if(arr[beg1]<arr[beg2])
```

to

```
if(!(arr[beg2]<arr[beg1]))
```

Comment: @Maciej: Thanks for the answer, but i don't think what you said is true. Here we have nothing to do with actual array values (arr[beg1] or arr[beg2]) What we are doing is we are checking that if the indices of the two pointers (not literally pointers)  have not completely reached the array end. If any one is left, we are simply copying it.

Comment: @Maciej these if conditions would be definitely required.Just think over it.

Comment: @Algorithmist Ok, maybe we have a misunderstanding. I'm not suggesting removing everything. I'm saying, that the loops can be executed unconditionally.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 The fact that the sort is not stable is another, minor issue and not something you ask about, but mergesort can be stable and a good implementation is, so I added the remark at the end.

Comment: @Maciej: But your comments doesn't hold in this case. Changing to what you said, won't make it stable either. But will make it erroneous.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Yeah my mistake. The simple solution is `if(arr[beg1]<=arr[beg2])`, but there is some reason to use the `<` operator only, so the better one is `if(!(arr[beg2]<arr[beg1]))`. I don't like unnecessary negation so I would prefer to use `if(arr[beg2]<arr[beg1])` and exchange the assignments below, but I didn't mention that :). Sorry.

Comment: @Maciej: if(arr[beg2]<arr[beg1]) is not required anyway...please think it. Refer some of the mergesort in the net so that you get an understanding. Here we aren't checking element values, but checking wether one of the subarrays have exhausted or not.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 I'm talking about the condition in the first `while` loop, where the merging is done and where the stability is determined.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 if `arr[beg1]==arr[beg2]` you copy an element from the second subarray, not the first one.It means the algorithm is not stable.

Comment: @Maceij: This only holds in case of duplicate elements. And in my case, the incorrect answer is not due to presence of duplicate elements. You can execute my code using non-duplicate elements, but still gives incorrect answer. Do you have any reason for that? There is no point in seeing these things, when the simple solution itself is not getting correct.Also, what you are telling now, you haven't mentioned earlier in the above code where you answered. Earlier you were telling something different, now something else. If you can figure out the real bug, then please let me know.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 In your case the incorrect answer is due to unnecessary `if` statements. Those while loops inside those `if` statements should be executed unconditionally. Did you try that? Try it. The note about lack of stability is a side note as I wrote. That's a completely unrelated thing.

Comment: @Maciej: if(beg1<end1) {
       while(beg1<=end1) temp[i++]=arr[beg1++];
   }
Do you mean this one?